# HybridAuth Facebook returned an invalid user id

Tags: php, facebook, authentication, social-networking, hybridauth

I am getting the following error:

```
Authentication failed. The user has canceled the authentication or the provider refused the connection.
Original error message: Authentication failed! Facebook returned an invalid user id.
```

tried a lot of things like to add in the base_facebook.php

```
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false
```

aswell as to improve the curl timeout, but it wont works.
The app isnt in facebook sandbox mode anymore so I literally have no guess left.

Comment: update: facebook debug error: URL returned a bad HTTP response code. Its because of hybridauth redirects to the endpoint, which isnt accessable by the client

Answer (score 2):

I just solved that problem by setting the "Is your App Secret embedded?" switch to "no" in the "advanced settings" tab on https://developers.facebook.com/x/apps/myid/settings/advanced/ .

Comment: I didnt find this setting, will be better if you have screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Recently this occurred due to facebook graph API change, v2.2 is depreciate
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

So we need to change php facebook-sdk for facebook graph api latest version v2.8. you can download the sdk from https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk

after replacing sdk you may need to add auto-load configurations for facebook sdk.

Comment: I am just facing the same problem. Apparently, Facebook is not sending "signed_request" POST variable anymore. Can you give me a clue how to solve this problem? I only have a base_facebook.php and facebook.php file. I dont have a lot of SDK files.

Comment: Hi @jstuardo Did you manage to get a solution to this. I am facing similar issue.