# Hybridauth Authentication failed! Facebook returned an invalid user id

Tags: php, facebook, authentication, facebook-php-sdk

I'm using Hybridauth library to create a signup with facebook link in my website i created and tested the code in localhost and everything worked perfectly but when  moved everything to the server it didn't work and gave me this error `Authentication failed! Facebook returned an invalid user id` i searched a lot on the internet for a solution but none of them worked

I tried all solutions suggested in this links:

- [Hybridauth - PHP - Facebook returned an invalid user id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14068425/hybridauth-php-facebook-returned-an-invalid-user-id)
- [HybridAuth Facebook returned an invalid user id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20777100/hybridauth-facebook-returned-an-invalid-user-id)
- [laravel4 hybridauth facebook Authentication failed! Facebook returned an invalid user id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17515618/laravel4-hybridauth-facebook-authentication-failed-facebook-returned-an-invalid)

So can you help me fix this problem please?

Any additional information needed just ask for them in the comments and thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing my server with this file

https://github.com/mistergiri/hybridauth/commit/0989180a863c89d9491cdf1543f56d6f8a34057a

i found that my server doesn't support ssl so i recompiled apache with OpenSSl installed form cpanel and everything worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Check your HybridAuth config.php file for the base URL.
I faced a similar issue. It should point to the correct path where the config.php resides.

Comment: What base url in config.php ?

Comment: Check this out [link](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/userguide/Configuration.html) It simply points to the starting point of the hybrid endpoint i.e the index.php

Comment: @Moghira the link shared seems to be broken now. Can you share here how to change the base_url

Comment: Seems like the library has been upgraded now. You can check the documentation here https://hybridauth.github.io/developer-ref-user-authentication.html