# hybridauth - codeigniter - php - fetal error on redirect url

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, hybridauth

i am using HybridAuth library for social logins.

everything is working perfectly on localhost.

and it was working on my hosting server too but now i am getting this errors suddenly:

when i tried with google:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'User profile
>   request failed! Google returned an error: exception 'Exception' with
>   message 'The Authorization Service has return: ' in
>   /home/moviesaints/public_html/dev/application/third_party/hybridauth/Hybrid/thirdparty/OAuth/OAuth2Client.php:82
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home/moviesaints/public_html/dev/application/third_party/hybridauth/Hybrid/Provider_Model_OAuth2.php(114):
>   OAuth2Client->authenticate('4/P-5SuqvrU0DDy...') #1
>   /home/moviesaints/public_html/dev/application/third_party/hybridauth/Hybrid/Endpoint.php(175): Hybrid_Provider_Model_OAuth2->loginFinish() #2
>   /home/moviesaints/public_html/dev/application/third_party/hybridauth/Hybrid/Endpoint.php(56):
>   Hybrid_Endpoint::processAuthDone() #3
>   /home/moviesaints/public_html/dev/application/third_party/hybridauth/index.php(15):
>   Hybrid_Endpoint::process() #4
>   /home/moviesaints/public_html/dev/application/controllers/user/hauth.php(298):
>   require_once('/home/moviesain...') #5 [internal function]:
>   HAuth->endpoint() #6 /home/mov in
>   /home/moviesaints/public_html/dev/application/third_party/hybridauth/Hybrid/Auth.php
>   on line 147

and when tried with facebook:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message
>   'Authentication failed! Facebook returned an invalid user id.' in
>   /home/moviesaints/public_html/dev/application/third_party/hybridauth/Hybrid/Providers/Facebook.php:91
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home/moviesaints/public_html/dev/application/third_party/hybridauth/Hybrid/Endpoint.php(175): Hybrid_Providers_Facebook->loginFinish() #1
>   /home/moviesaints/public_html/dev/application/third_party/hybridauth/Hybrid/Endpoint.php(56):
>   Hybrid_Endpoint::processAuthDone() #2
>   /home/moviesaints/public_html/dev/application/third_party/hybridauth/index.php(15):
>   Hybrid_Endpoint::process() #3
>   /home/moviesaints/public_html/dev/application/controllers/user/hauth.php(298):
>   require_once('/home/moviesain...') #4 [internal function]:
>   HAuth->endpoint() #5
>   /home/moviesaints/public_html/dev/system/core/CodeIgniter.php(359):
>   call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #6
>   /home/moviesaints/public_html/dev/index.php(202):
>   require_once('/home/moviesain...') #7 {main} Next exception
>   'Exception' with message 'Authentic in
>   /home/moviesaints/public_html/dev/application/third_party/hybridauth/Hybrid/Auth.php
>   on line 147

I have tried following solutions but still facing the same problem:

[hybridauth-php-facebook-returned-an-invalid-user-id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14068425/hybridauth-php-facebook-returned-an-invalid-user-id)

[hybridauth-facebook-returned-an-invalid-user-id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20777100/hybridauth-facebook-returned-an-invalid-user-id)

[laravel4-hybridauth-facebook-authentication-failed-facebook-returned-an-invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17515618/laravel4-hybridauth-facebook-authentication-failed-facebook-returned-an-invalid)

[Github Solution](https://github.com/hybridauth/hybridauth/issues/188)

[Google group Solution](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/hybridauth/zgV4RHvvlFk/Of2Gnw-NarsJ)

Help please, It will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is true or not but after I was able to get my installation working I still could not get Facebook to work, no matter how hard I tried. My guess is that the SDK files used by Hybridauth for Facebook are deprecated. Facebook released new versions and quite a reworked SDK recently. That could be why there seem to be a lot of people suffering from issues with the Facebook provider right now.

Comment: thanks inquam for your help. actually i was facing this problem just because of my hosting server. when i changed the server its working fine.